# How do I mock a django signal handler?

Tags: python, django, mocking, signals, django-signals

I have a signal_handler connected through a decorator, something like this very simple one:

```
@receiver(post_save, sender=User, 
          dispatch_uid='myfile.signal_handler_post_save_user')
def signal_handler_post_save_user(sender, *args, **kwargs):
   # do stuff
```

What I want to do is to mock it **with the mock library http://www.voidspace.org.uk/python/mock/** in a test, to check how many times django calls it. My code at the moment is something like:

```
def test_cache():
    with mock.patch('myapp.myfile.signal_handler_post_save_user') as mocked_handler:
        # do stuff that will call the post_save of User
    self.assert_equal(mocked_handler.call_count, 1)
```

The problem here is that the original signal handler is called even if mocked, most likely because the `@receiver` decorator is storing a copy of the signal handler somewhere, so I'm mocking the wrong code.

So the question: how do I mock my signal handler to make my test work?

Note that if I change my signal handler to:

```
def _support_function(*args, **kwargs):
    # do stuff

@receiver(post_save, sender=User, 
          dispatch_uid='myfile.signal_handler_post_save_user')
def signal_handler_post_save_user(sender, *args, **kwargs):
   _support_function(*args, **kwargs)
```

and I mock `_support_function` instead, everything works as expected.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

So, I ended up with a kind-of solution: mocking a signal handler simply means to connect the mock itself to the signal, so this exactly is what I did:

```
def test_cache():
    with mock.patch('myapp.myfile.signal_handler_post_save_user', autospec=True) as mocked_handler:
        post_save.connect(mocked_handler, sender=User, dispatch_uid='test_cache_mocked_handler')
        # do stuff that will call the post_save of User
    self.assertEquals(mocked_handler.call_count, 1)  # standard django
    # self.assert_equal(mocked_handler.call_count, 1)  # when using django-nose
```

Notice that `autospec=True` in `mock.patch` is required in order to make `post_save.connect` to correctly work on a `MagicMock`, otherwise django will raise some exceptions and the connection will fail.

Comment: shouldn't `assert_equal` be `assertEquals(...)` ?

Comment: It depends on the testing suite you're using; django by default uses `unittest`, which has `assertEquals` as you say; I always use `nose` which is, in my opinion, superior in many aspects, and nose comes with a `assert_equal`. When writing my answer I copy/pasted from my production code, that's why you see `assert_equal` there. I edited the answer to respect the django default, thank you for pointing this out

Comment: thanks! I also use nose but never realized that assert_equal existed

Comment: This does not work for me either. The 'original' handler is still called.

Comment: You are not actually testing the signal, instead you ending up up testing the signal functionality of core django, but not your custom code. If you replace `signal_handler_post_save_user` with any other function the test case will pass, that's because you explicitly have made that handler function subscribe for the `post_save` event, then again checking back if that handler function is triggered. This way you aren't really making sure, that your handler function that you had written and was supposed to run on `post_save` event is getting triggered or not.

Comment: what exactly is your "mock" object? unittest.mock?

Answer (score 27):

Possibly a better idea is to mock out the functionality *inside* the signal handler rather than the handler itself. Using the OP's code:

```
@receiver(post_save, sender=User, dispatch_uid='myfile.signal_handler_post_save_user')
def signal_handler_post_save_user(sender, *args, **kwargs):
  do_stuff()  # <-- mock this

def do_stuff():
   ... do stuff in here
```

Then mock `do_stuff`:

```
with mock.patch('myapp.myfile.do_stuff') as mocked_handler:
    self.assert_equal(mocked_handler.call_count, 1)
```

Comment: Why is this a better idea?

Comment: I figured it out this as well as I was digging out what the hell reason was. I found the function has been called, so It was fine for me to add a new method just for test, and to check if that method was called.

Answer (score 4):

You can mock a django signal by mocking the ModelSignal class at `django.db.models.signals.py` like this:

```
@patch("django.db.models.signals.ModelSignal.send")
def test_overwhelming(self, mocker_signal):
    obj = Object()
```

That should do the trick. Note that this will mock ALL signals no matter which object you are using.

If by any chance you use the `mocker` library instead, it can be done like this:

```
from mocker import Mocker, ARGS, KWARGS

def test_overwhelming(self):
    mocker = Mocker()
    # mock the post save signal
    msave = mocker.replace("django.db.models.signals")
    msave.post_save.send(KWARGS)
    mocker.count(0, None)

    with mocker:
        obj = Object()
```

It's more lines but it works pretty well too :)

Answer (score 3):

take a look at mock_django . It has support for signals

https://github.com/dcramer/mock-django/blob/master/tests/mock_django/signals/tests.py

Comment: thank you @mossplix, I knew about django_mock, but I can't/don't want to add new requirements to the project, that's why I asked specifically a solution using python mock

Answer (score 3):

In django 1.9 you can mock all receivers with something like this

```
# replace actual receivers with mocks
mocked_receivers = []
for i, receiver in enumerate(your_signal.receivers):
    mock_receiver = Mock()
    your_signal.receivers[i] = (receiver[0], mock_receiver)
    mocked_receivers.append(mock_receiver)

...  # whatever your test does

# ensure that mocked receivers have been called as expected
for mocked_receiver in mocked_receivers:
    assert mocked_receiver.call_count == 1
    mocked_receiver.assert_called_with(*your_args, sender="your_sender", signal=your_signal, **your_kwargs)
```

This replaces all receivers with mocks, eg ones you've registered, ones pluggable apps have registered and ones that django itself has registered. Don't be suprised if you use this on `post_save` and things start breaking.

You may want to inspect the receiver to determine if you actually want to mock it.

Answer (score 2):

There is a way to mock django signals with a small class.

You should keep in mind that this would only mock the function as a django signal handler and not the original function; for example, if a m2mchange trigers a call to a function that calls your handler directly, mock.call_count would not be incremented. You would need a separate mock to keep track of those calls.

Here is the class in question:

```
class LocalDjangoSignalsMock():
    def __init__(self, to_mock):
        """ 
        Replaces registered django signals with MagicMocks

        :param to_mock: list of signal handlers to mock
        """
        self.mocks = {handler:MagicMock() for handler in to_mock}
        self.reverse_mocks = {magicmock:mocked
                              for mocked,magicmock in self.mocks.items()}
        django_signals = [signals.post_save, signals.m2m_changed]
        self.registered_receivers = [signal.receivers
                                     for signal in django_signals]

    def _apply_mocks(self):
        for receivers in self.registered_receivers:
            for receiver_index in xrange(len(receivers)):
                handler = receivers[receiver_index]
                handler_function = handler[1]()
                if handler_function in self.mocks:
                    receivers[receiver_index] = (
                        handler[0], self.mocks[handler_function])

    def _reverse_mocks(self):
        for receivers in self.registered_receivers:
            for receiver_index in xrange(len(receivers)):
                handler = receivers[receiver_index]
                handler_function = handler[1]
                if not isinstance(handler_function, MagicMock):
                    continue
                receivers[receiver_index] = (
                    handler[0], weakref.ref(self.reverse_mocks[handler_function]))

    def __enter__(self):
        self._apply_mocks()
        return self.mocks

    def __exit__(self, *args):
        self._reverse_mocks()
```

Example usage

```
to_mock = [my_handler]
with LocalDjangoSignalsMock(to_mock) as mocks:
    my_trigger()
    for mocked in to_mock:
        assert(mocks[mocked].call_count)
        # 'function {0} was called {1}'.format(
        #      mocked, mocked.call_count)
```

Answer (score 1):

As you mentioned,
`mock.patch('myapp.myfile._support_function')` is correct but `mock.patch('myapp.myfile.signal_handler_post_save_user')` is wrong.

I think the reason is:

When init you test, some file import the signal's realization python file, then `@receive` decorator create a new signal connection.

In the test, `mock.patch('myapp.myfile._support_function')` will create another signal connection, so the original signal handler is called even if mocked.

Try to disconnect the signal connection before `mock.patch('myapp.myfile._support_function')`, like

```py
post_save.disconnect(signal_handler_post_save_user)
with mock.patch("review.signals. signal_handler_post_save_user", autospec=True) as handler:
    #do stuff
```